# DB update - long running operation fails

Tags: mysql, performance, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I am using hibernate to put an object into DB. The DB is MYSQL community edition.
The whole update runs into transaction.

The code that does it is this:

> getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(order);

There is no problem when the order is small, but when I tested the scenario with close to 1 000 000 items I ran into this issue:

```
11-22@12:56:48 DEBUG PersistOrderServiceImpl [flow.ottoImportOrderPlacementInboundFlow.1] - saving order instance::
[Order [orderId=080661, vatOrderNumber=SODE000001, orderDate=Tue Nov 08 10:12:37 CET 2011, shippingMethod=STANDARD, ....

11-22@13:02:12 ERROR JDBCTransaction [flow.ottoImportOrderPlacementInboundFlow.1] - JDBC rollback failed
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
.....
....
11-22@13:02:12 ERROR TransactionInterceptor [flow.ottoImportOrderPlacementInboundFlow.1] - Application exception overridden by rollback exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Field.setConnection(Field.java:972)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.getGeneratedKeysInternal(StatementImpl.java:1912)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.getGeneratedKeysInternal(StatementImpl.java:1905)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.getGeneratedKeys(StatementImpl.java:1885)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1749)
        at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:97)
        at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:57)
......
......
```

It seems that the problem is manifesting after around 5 minutes and 24 seconds or 324 seconds total.

I cannot find anything in MySQL log about it.

It seems it is not memory related, because when I lower the memory the exception is different:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

I don't know if that is some kind of bug in Hibernate of MySQL or it is some setting that limits the time that a an update/connection/transaction can run.

I could not find anything related in MySQL documentation or in Hibernate settings.

I would appreciate any help with debugging or resolving this issue.

RESOLVED: Problem was in the file c3p0.properties that was in my tomcat lib.
It contains: c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout=300 which is more or less the time after which I get the error. After I removed it the update passed, no problem.

Comment: so you are creating 1mil Order objects and persisting them with hibernate? can you post the hibernate save code?

Comment: No, I am creating only one order with 1 mil items. Will post the code to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database connection pool is configured with a timeout value. Once a transaction has started (borrowed a connection from the pool) and does not finish (does not release the connection to the pool) before this timeout value, the connection is closed by the database connection pool (marked as abandoned). When hibernate tries to commit the transaction (note that hibernate has no way of knowing if the connection has been closed here), the driver thoughs an exception. Try to break down your transaction into further smaller transactions (Commit the items in batches). Once all the orders have been inserted into the DB, insert your Order object. However, your application code should take care of a batch commit failing and the roll-back logic thereafter.

Comment: I think I found the reason - it is within the file c3p0.properties that is in my tomcat lib. It contains: c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout=300 which is more or less the time after I get this error.

Comment: After I removed the file, the problem is no longer there. So you are right, it is pooling problem. Thanks!

Comment: You should be careful with that as removing the entry for timeout may cause some undesirable effects. Do read the documentation of the driver and the connection pool you are using before calling this a permanent fix.